# css multiple rectangles horizontally arranged

Tags: html, css

I'm at a loss with this seemingly simple css: How do I modify the code below to have three or more different parallelograms, horizontally arranged, with some space between them ?

html:

```
<div id="parallelogram"></div>
```

css:

```
#parallelogram {
width: 20px;
height: 60px;
margin: 0 0 0 20px;
-webkit-transform: skew(-11deg);
   -moz-transform: skew(-11deg);
     -o-transform: skew(-11deg);
      -ms-transform: skew(-11deg);
background: #0272a7;
}
```

Comment: did u tried it with `float`?

Comment: `<div id="parallelogram"</div>` should be `<div id="parallelogram"></div>`, you can't have all as `ids` you have to switch to classes.

Comment: @Mritunjay Actually it should be `<div class="parallelogram"></div>` to *have three or more...* of such element.

Answer (score 2):

in short

```
float:left;
```

Will made them arrange horizontally instead of jumping to the next line after each one. Also, since you say "several rectangles" I took the liberty of using a classname instead.

I made a few assumptions. However, please see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amenadiel/yk1Lyche/) to see it's what you were asking

Answer (score 2):

Use `inline-block` to make it align next to each.

```
 .parallelogram {
 width: 20px;
 height: 60px;
 margin: 0 0 0 20px;
 -webkit-transform: skew(-11deg);
-moz-transform: skew(-11deg);
 -o-transform: skew(-11deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-11deg);
background: #0272a7;
display:inline-block;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/88c7w6xu/3/)

Comment: Inline block is the way to go...floats are overused :P

Comment: @ IDs should be unique in the document. It's better to use Classes instead.

Comment: Thank you ! Now if I wanted a different style on each parallelogram does this mean a new class for each or is there some other way ?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `class` instead `id`

```
<div class="parallelogram"></div>
<div class="parallelogram"></div>
<div class="parallelogram"></div>
<div class="parallelogram"></div>
```

CSS -

```
.parallelogram {
width: 20px;
height: 60px;
margin: 0 0 0 20px;
-webkit-transform: skew(-11deg);
   -moz-transform: skew(-11deg);
     -o-transform: skew(-11deg);
      -ms-transform: skew(-11deg);
background: #0272a7;
 float: left;
}
```

Or use `display: inline-block`

```
.parallelogram {
width: 20px;
height: 60px;
margin: 0 0 0 20px;
-webkit-transform: skew(-11deg);
   -moz-transform: skew(-11deg);
     -o-transform: skew(-11deg);
      -ms-transform: skew(-11deg);
background: #0272a7;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vL9raeqa/2/)